# QDockWidget - fonts getting caught off (decender part)

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

On QdockWidgets part of the text is being caught off, the "tail" part or decender in typography terminology. So for example Chapters and Settings, the "p" and the "g" are cut

```
/******** QDockWidget - this controls the top header for widgets ********/

QDockWidget {

    titlebar-close-icon: url(:/Controls/ic_close2.png);
    titlebar-normal-icon: url(:/Controls/ic_undock.png);
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

QDockWidget::title {

    text-align: left; /* align the text to the left */
    background: #2e333b;
    padding-left: 27px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

QDockWidget::close-button, QDockWidget::float-button {

    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: transparent;
}

QDockWidget::close-button:hover, QDockWidget::float-button:hover {

    border: 1px solid grey;
}

QDockWidget::close-button:pressed, QDockWidget::float-button:pressed {
    padding: 1px -1px -1px 1px;

}

/*_______QDockWidget_______*/
```

[image: screenshot[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in border and padding here:

```
QDockWidget::title {    
    <...>
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

For example, you can reduce padding or remove border.